# How do I stop eevee shadows changing shape each frame?

Tags: eevee-render-engine, shadows

[image]I am doing an animation in eevee with one spot light, volumetric fog, the camera and light moving together over different models/objects..
My problem is each time it changes frame all the objects shadows change shape drastically, creating a jittery, flickering shadow in the animation.
I've tried increasing samples and other changes but nothing helps the shadows stay one shape!

Comment: What do you mean by changing shape? It's normal for shadows to be longer/shorter as the light source moves. A screenshot could help. And do you have one light or two lights?

Comment: Ok I have added a picture of 3 frames in a row, its not a natural change of shadow at all, looks really bad when animated... other more solid objects do the same thing.. There is just one main light source, a spot light. There is 2 other small lights but they  can only be seen when the camera comes to them..